# How to detect browser information from WebAssembly module?

Tags: javascript, c++, browser, webassembly, emscripten

How to initiate a C++ variable (compiled to WebAssembly) from a value detected through JavaScript at launch (like current `screen.availWidth`)?

This code needs to be initiated from WebAssembly module, so the user can't inject a different value than the real one.

Comment: @Dan This is a C++ question as it is mentioned in the object itself, why you keep removing the C++ tag and downvoting the question? Webassembly can be generated from rust which is not what we want here.

Please look in the tags of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421002/passing-a-c-function-to-a-javascript-function-in-emscripten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

You can run a JavaScript code from inside your C++ function. Such JS code has access to all objects you usually would have access to when running it in a web browser. To do that we will use [EM_ASM_INT](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-javascript-from-native) macro which executes JS code returning an `int` value.

## Quick solution

We inject the JS code inside the C++ code `example.cpp`. The use of `int main()` function makes sure the code will automatically execute when loading the page without the need for loading the WebAssembly module manually. However, you can use a different function, export it, and execute it on your webpage as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emscripten.h>

int main()
{
   int screen_width = EM_ASM_INT(
       return screen.availWidth;);
   std::cout << "Screen width=" << screen_width << std::endl;
}
```

We compile the above `example.cpp` code with the [Emscripten compiler](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html) as follows:

```sh
emcc example.cpp -o example.html
```

The output is a webpage with embedded `int main()` function with JS code inside it (truly, inception).
To run the code while allowing for the Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), we will use [emrun](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Running-html-files-with-emrun.html) tool (I could not run the example on Firefox, so I have used Chrome instead):

```sh
emrun --browser chrome example.html
```

## Comment

This approach works for JS code with the return value of type scalar `int` (using `EM_ASM_INT`), `double` (with `EM_ASM_DOUBLE`), but also array of `char*` (using `EM_ASM_INT` with careful and manual memory management as shown [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.EM_ASM_INT)).